# R - Appending to lists with names l_A, l_B, l_C ... etc. using for loops and built-in LETTERS

Tags: r, for-loop, append, eval, variable-names

I've generated empty lists corresponding to every letter of the alphabet. The names of the lists take the form `l_A, l_B`, ...
I also have a one-column data frame populated with strings (all lowercase, no symbols). I want to sort these strings by their first letter into the corresponding list, e.g., the word "aardvark" would go in list `l_A`.

I'm having problems calling the correct list when iterating through the data frame. This is my attempt to sort using for loops. For the example, I'm using a random list of words (all lowercase) built using the library "OpenRepGrid" to build the starting data frame.

```
install.packages("OpenRepGrid")
library(OpenRepGrid)

# random words data frame
df <- data.frame(tolower(randomWords(100)))

# lists for each letter
for (i in 1:26){
    nam <- paste0("l_", LETTERS[i])
    assign(nam, list()) 
    }

# sorting words in data frame into lists using for loops
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:26){
    if (substr(df[i, 1], 1, 1) == letters[j]){
      append(eval(as.name(paste0("l_", LETTERS[j]))), df[i, 1])
    }
  }
}
```

The empty lists generate correctly and I don't get any errors, but all of my lists end up still being empty. This is leading me to think the issue is trying to call the lists using `eval(as.name(paste0("l_", LETTERS[j])))`. I know I could write if statements for each list rather than using a nested for loop, but this is cumbersome with 26 lists!

Even if you have a much more elegant method, I'd still like to know what I need to do for my current method to work as well as your own recommended solutions.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is creating NULL `list` in a loop.  It can be done in more easier ways as well

```
> l_A
list()
```

In the second loop, we need to `get` the value of the `list` created for `append`ing and `assign` back to the same object

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:26){
    if (substr(df[i, 1], 1, 1) == letters[j]){
      tmp <- paste0("l_", LETTERS[j])
      assign(tmp, append(get(tmp), df[i, 1]))
    }
  }
}
```

-checking

```
> l_A
[[1]]
[1] "as"

[[2]]
[1] "airplane"

[[3]]
[1] "as"

[[4]]
[1] "away"

[[5]]
[1] "airplane"

[[6]]
[1] "airplane"
...
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. How would I loop through the lists to assign the length of the longest list as a value to a variable "max"? E.g. if the longest list has 12 words, "max" would equal 12

Comment: @DeeG Not clear.  Did you meant `max(lengths(mget(paste0("l_", LETTERS))))#
[1] 18`

Comment: If instead of lists, I have character vectors (called ```v_A```, ```v_B```, etc.), how do I set the length of these vectors to all be the same as ```max(lengths(mget(paste0("v_", LETTERS))))``` ?

Comment: @DeeG the same code should work i.e. `v_A <- 1:5; v_B <- 6:11; max(lengths(mget(paste0("v_", LETTERS[1:2]))))#
[1] 6`

Comment: the code works, but I don't know how to then use that code and set the length of all the vectors to be the max length without doing it manually for each vector

Comment: @DeeG lets say you get the `list` as `lst1 <- mget(paste0("v_", LETTERS[1:2])); mx <- max(lengths(lst1)); lst2 <- lapply(lst1, "length<-", mx);list2env(lst2, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Now, check the lengths again `lengths(mget(paste0("v_", LETTERS[1:2])))#
v_A v_B 
  6   6`  The `length<-` pads NA to the right wherever the length is short

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240458/discussion-between-dee-g-and-akrun).